# How block user for 40 minutes after 6 failed login attempts in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a script for login throttling. I want to prevent a user from logging in for 40 minutes if he/she was unable to log 6 times. I have created a `login_attempts` table with columns: `ip_address`, `username`, `created_at`. when the user submits the login form I add the IP address of the user with the username in the database. then on the login page, I am showing the login form if the user has not exceeded the maximum number of login attempts. If the user has exceeded the maximum number of login attempts, instead I show the error and also delete the logs older than 40 minutes on the login page. but after the 6 failed login attempts I still see the login form.

Any suggestions?

```
<?php

// Login Page

delete_records_older_than(40, 'created_at', 'login_attempts');

if (has_exceeded_max_login_attempts($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], 6)) {
  // please try again after 40 minutes
} else {
  // show the login form
}
```

Form Processing Script

```
<?php

// ON Form submit

if (login) {
  // mark user as logged in
} else {
  add_login_attempt_in_db($username, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
}
```

Here are my functions:

```
function add_login_attempt_in_db($username, $address)
{
  global $db;
  $sql = 'INSERT INTO login_attempts(username, ip_address, created_at) VALUES (?, ?, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)';
  $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($db);
  mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql);

  mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ss', $username, $address);
  $result = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
  mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
  if (!$result) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}

function delete_records_older_than($minutes, $date_column, $table)
{
  global $db;
  $sql = 'DELETE FROM ' . $table . ' WHERE ' . $date_column . ' < (NOW() - INTERVAL ' . $minutes . ' MINUTE)';
  $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($db);
  mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql);
  mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
}

function has_exceeded_max_login_attempts($ip_address, $limit)
{
  global $db;
  $sql = 'SELECT COUNT(id) AS attempts FROM login_attempts WHERE ip_address LIKE ? AND created_at > (now() - interval 40 minute)';
  $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($db);
  mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql);
  mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $ip_address);
  mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
  $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
  mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
  // fetch result
  $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
  return $result['attempts'] >= $limit;
}
```

Comment: You are using `>` so if there were 6 attempts the condition would still not be true. It has to be at least 7

Comment: Also, since you're using `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` a malicious user could defeat this entirely by using a VPN. I'd drop the ip address and log by username only